# Using FULL TEXT and exact match for results with words below ft_min_word_len

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I have a database with names. This has a full text index.

ft_min_word_len is set to 4. I am on shard hosting, so this cannot be changed.

Sometimes queries may contain words less than 4 characters.

For example, if the table has rows for Ben Smith and John Smith a query for `MATCH(name) AGAINST('Ben Smith')` returns both rows, with equal scores as 'Ben' is ignored, being below 4 characters.

I need Ben Smith to return with the highest score. I figure fudging the score value somehow with an additional search on an exact match would help, but I am stumped on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use full text search to reduce the number of rows and use `like` for your final score:

```
select ((name like '%Ben%') + (name like '%Smith%')) as my_score
from t
where MATCH(name) AGAINST('Ben Smith');
```

Comment: Gave this a go. Didn't work. They both return with a score of 1.

Comment: I made a change to your suggestion. Instead of name like with wildcards, I simply did name = 'search term' and then ordered by my_score with secondary ordering of the MATCH score. This works. Thanks.

Comment: @BobHoskins . . . `'John Smith'` should return "1" for this expression, `'Ben Smith'` should return "2".